# whatnew not working: InvalidUseOfMatcfhers exception

Tags: unit-testing, junit, powermock

I am trying to mock the following call:

```
token = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(token), "UTF-8");
```

The following gives

```
@Test(expected = InternalServiceException.class)
public void testGetDecodedVlsAuthorizationTokenWithException() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.whenNew(String.class).withArguments(any(byte[].class), String.class).thenThrow(new UnsupportedEncodingException());
    brazilConfigurationManager.getDecodedVlsAuthorizationToken();
}
```

I have used `@PrepareForTest(BrazilConfigurationManager.class)` as suggested [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) under `whatNew` section.

On this I get InvalidUseOfMatchersException.

I also tried

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(String.class).withAnyArguments().thenThrow(new UnsupportedEncodingException());
```

but that also does not work.

Any suggestions on what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `String.class` argument in `withArguments` with `eq(String.class)` in the line: 
`PowerMockito.whenNew(String.class).withArguments(any(byte[].class), String.class).thenThrow(new UnsupportedEncodingException());`

Also to get the specific constructor when there are many constructors available (as in this case), then you need to find the specific constructor using `withParameterTypes` as given below:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(String.class)
    .withParameterTypes(byte[].class, String.class)
    .withArguments(any(byte[].class), eq(String.class))
    .thenThrow(new UnsupportedEncodingException());
```

When you use matchers in arguments, all arguments have to be matchers or none. Meaning you can't mix matchers like `any(Some.class)` and real arguments like `String.class`. So the way you get around is by using a matcher for real arguments by wrapping them in an `eq` matcher.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get `TooManyConstructorsFoundException`. any clue?

Comment: Try `PowerMockito.whenNew(String.class).withParameterTypes(byte[].class, String.class).withArguments(any(byte[].class), eq(String.class)).thenThrow(new UnsupportedEncodingException())` which will find the constructor with the types mentioned.

Comment: Yup. Git it. Please put it in answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I do not know about this but I used `isA` construct